macOS won't allow any local network's webpages after upgrading to macOS 15 Sequoia
I am running multiple homelab services (e.g., PVE virtual machines, Synology NAS, etc.) and they are working properly until I upgraded my MBP to macOS 15 Sequoia. After the upgrade my Mac cannot access ANY homelab's service webpages from MBP, because browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc.) consider they are unsafe:

I know those services provide self-signed certificates only and macOS consider they are "unsafe", but they have been running, used by myself for years and all can be opened on macOS 14, and all my Windows/mobile devices can access them without any issues. I believe there must be some security settings changed on macOS 15 and I would like to seek for help on configuration on this, thanks!

Does this help https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/keychain-access/kyca2431/mac It is about adding certificates to a keychain.
